# Javascript Fetch inside a map

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch-api, github-api

I have a website/portfolio where I display all my projects using the Github API. My goal is to create a filter for these projects, so I created a file in the root of some repositories called "built-with.json", that file exists in **only two repositories** just for test purpose, that is a array of technologies I used in the project (example: ["React", "Javascript", ...]). So I need to fetch the Github APi(that part it's working well), then fetch that file, and return a new Array of projects but with an "filters" key where the value is the array inside of "built-with.json". Example:

Github API return (example of just one project returning):

```
[{
"id": 307774617,
"node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkzMDc3NzQ2MTc=",
"name": "vanilla-javascript-utility-functions",
"full_name": "RodrigoWebDev/vanilla-javascript-utility-functions",
"private": false
}]
```

New array of objects that a I need:

```
[{
"id": 307774617,
"node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkzMDc3NzQ2MTc=",
"name": "vanilla-javascript-utility-functions",
"full_name": "RodrigoWebDev/vanilla-javascript-utility-functions",
"private": false,
"filters": ["HTML5", "CSS3", "JS", "React"]
}]
```

This is what I did:

```
const url = "https://api.github.com/users/RodrigoWebDev/repos?per_page=100&sort=created";
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
      return data.map(item => {
        //item.full_name returns the repositorie name
        fetch(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${item.full_name}/master/built-with.json`)
          .then(data => {
            item["filters"] = data
            return item
          })
      })
    })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

But it does not work! I get this in the console:

[image]

Someone can help me? Thanks in advance

Note: Sorry if you find some gramatical errors, my English it's a working in progress

Comment: A couple of things here. You don't need the `.then()` chained onto `fetch()`. `fetch()` returns a promise. `Array.prototype.map()` returns an array. Put together, you end up with an array of promises. You can resolve the array of promises with `Promise.all(arrayOfPs)`

Comment: You need to chain a `promise.all`. please look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: You miss out a `return` before the inner `fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

1. Inside of map function you do not return any result
2. Result of your map function will actually be another Promise (because of fetch inside).

So what you need to do:

1. Return promise from map - as a result you will have array of promises
2. Wait for all promises from point 1 using Promise.all

Something like this:

```
    var url1 = "https://api.github.com/users/RodrigoWebDev/repos?per_page=100&sort=created";
    var datum = fetch(url1)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
          return Promise.all(data.map(item => {
            //item.full_name returns the repositorie name
            return fetch(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${item.full_name}/master/built-with.json`)
              .then(data => {
                item["filters"] = data
                return item
              })
          }));
        }).then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: Hey Nikitia. It worked, but the new array of objects returned is not the array of filters, but the return of fetch, see https://ibb.co/t4Y04gQ .I tried to pass the repsonse to json like this https://ibb.co/VV0XT00 but it did not work

Comment: to understand what is going on there, i would need to see what are you receiving, you could try .text() instead of .json() - maybe it will give you a clue

Comment: with .text() it worked, but it returned an string ( https://jsfiddle.net/gtqjna1y/ check the "my-website" repositorie in the returned array), I can change the string to an array, but is there some way to get it as an array? To you understand better, there are two repositories with the file "built-with.json" that I want to fetch, the repostories is my-website and border-radius-previewer, If a can make it work for these two I will create thie file inside each project to build my filter

Comment: I need to see exactly what you receiving from network, it might be that json is stringified there or something like that, you could try JSON.parse on text() and see if that works

Comment: Please, check this url: jsfiddle.net/gtqjna1y , in dev tools console check the "my-website" repositorie in the returned array, there is what exactly what I'm receiving, or you can see this screenshot https://ibb.co/t4Y04gQ. JSON.parse does not work because the response is not a JSON stringified but the promise object

Comment: Am i missing something or it actually worked? https://ibb.co/qWzVB48
And from screenshot you provided it is not a promise object, is a response object, as it should be

Comment: Yeah, it returned a string, but I need an Array. Like I said, I can simple do a split() to create an array from that string, but is there some way to receive an array directly? And yes, you are right, when I use "data.json()" it returns the response object, not the array that I need

Comment: that string doesn't seem to be an array, so your api doesn't return an array, so yeah you should build your own logic to cast it to array, split or any other method.

Comment: that's weird! See this example https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RodrigoWebDev/my-website/master/built-with.json, this is the file that I mentioned early that contains an array inside and I'm fetching the content of this file, may I'm building this file in a wrong way?

Answer (score 11):

A couple of things here. You don't need the .then() chained onto fetch(). fetch() returns a promise. Array.prototype.map() returns an array. Put together, you end up with an array of promises. You can resolve the array of promises with Promise.all(arrayOfPs)

EDIT: After your comments and reviewing your question, I've rewritten this so that it retrieves the skills from the filtered list of repositories.

```js
const url = `https://api.github.com/users/RodrigoWebDev/repos?per_page=100&sort=created`;

(async() => {
  // Final results 
  let results;
  try {
    // Get all repositories
    const repos = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
    const responses = await Promise.all(
      // Request file named 'build-with.json' from each repository
      repos.map((item) => {
        return fetch(
          `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${item.full_name}/master/built-with.json`
        );
      })
    );
    // Filter out all non-200 http response codes (essentially 404 errors)
    const filteredResponses = responses.filter((res) => res.status === 200);
    results = Promise.all(
      // Get the project name from the URL and skills from the file
      filteredResponses.map(async(fr) => {
        const project = fr.url.match(/(RodrigoWebDev)\/(\S+)(?=\/master)/)[2];
        const skills = await fr.json();
        return {
          project: project,
          skills: skills
        };
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
  }
  results.then((s) => console.log(s));
})();
```

Comment: Your example is returnning a new Array of promises, I need a new array of github projects with the key "filters", how I reach this result?

Comment: the example is returning an array of HTTP responses. They are all 404 errors. I don't think I understand what you mean or what you see in the result.

Comment: I re-read your question. You don't identify which repos have this magic file with your "filters". Provide a repo that has that file in it and I'll retrieve it and print it's content.

Comment: https://github.com/RodrigoWebDev/my-website and https://github.com/RodrigoWebDev/border-radius-previewer

Comment: @Rodrigo - there you go!

Comment: Inside `array.map()` I use `fetch()` as in the example. However, I have `await Promise.all()` outside map and inside `await (await fetch(..).json())`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the fetch wasn't being returned hence the .map() was returning undefined. May I suggest a solution using async-await.

```js
const url = "https://api.github.com/users/RodrigoWebDev/repos?per_page=100&sort=created";

getData(url).then(data => console.log(data));
  
async function getData(url){
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  const arrOfPromises = data.map(item => fetch(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${item.full_name}/master/built-with.json`)
  );
  return Promise.all(arrOfPromises);
}
```

Comment: you didn't even change my variable name :-) LOL

Comment: I'm sorry, I did use your example as a reference. I also upvoted your answer because it was the correct one. I will delete this answer if that's a problem for you. @RandyCasburn

Comment: NO - don't delete your answer! It is just as valid as mine. I was just teasing you.

Comment: Your example is returnning a new Array of promises, I need a new array of github projects with the key "filters", how I reach this result?